# If $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ do not exist, can the $\lim [f(x)+g(x)]$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: This is a question from Calculus by Michael Spivak, how do start answering this question?]
This is a question from Calculus by Michael Spivak, how do start answering this question?

Comment: What are your thoughts for each question?

Comment: Yes. For example: $f=-g=\sin$ and $a \to \infty$.

Comment: You should have a few examples in your bag of tricks. Do you have a function that has no limit at (for instance) $a=0$? And a function that does? Call the first one $g$ and the second one $f$. What about $f+g$? What about $f-g$?

Comment: I want to prove each statement by using proof methods, I don't have any given function. So how do I start proving? I tried using proof by contrapositive by using epsilon delta definition of a limit but ended up confused.

Comment: I'd rather not reside on examples because I want to know how it really worked by proving the general case.

Comment: I would not attempt to go that route if I were you.  Once you show that a) can be true for both, that answers b) and d).  All of these are existential proofs, which means that an example is the best method to prove they are correct.  If you need to prove one is incorrect, then this becomes a universal and that is something you need to prove more rigorously (for instance I believe c) cannot exist, so that one you would want to prove with something like proof by contradiction).

Comment: If a proposition is false, all it takes is one counterexample to prove it. That is a valid proof method.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Thanks Jared for the clear explanation!

Comment: Jason Zimba, Isn't it If a proposition is claimed to be true, then all it takes is one counterexample to show it is not true?

Comment: @shinobi20 That's for a universal.  You are trying to prove something exists.  I'll give a hint for part c): let h(x) = f(x) + g(x), then show that the $\lim (h(x) - f(x))$ exists.

Comment: @shinobi20: I think Jason Zimbabwe means that a single counterexample proves a proposition to be false.

Comment: @shinobi20 no, he was correct in what he said.  How much do you know about predicate logic and first order logic?  There are two basic types of expressions in first order logic (they can be mixed and more complicated): $\forall x: P(x)$ and $\exists x: P(x)$.  The first is read "for all x, P(x) is true" and the second reads "there exists an x such that P(x) is true".  If you want to prove that a universal is false, then it becomes an existential expression: $\neg \forall x: P(x) \equiv \exists x: \neg P(x)$.  So you just have to show that a counterexample exists.

Comment: Thanks Jared! Btw, what other calculus books should I read in order to understand more on limits and I want to know the theory behind it (calculus by spivak is good but I want to add more insights on limits because sometimes spivak's method of explanation is so short that I get lost when answering some of the problems), not just some plug in and answer type of explanation.

Comment: I can't really recommend any books.  My advice would be to continue studying calculus.  You won't learn the concepts until you have to really use them and use them often.  For limits, my guess is that a real analysis course would force you to really understand limits (but that's probably far off, I'm guessing).  I still have trouble with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs because I just don't really ever use them (my background is physics--so integrals, differentials, etc. is more my forte).

Comment: Thank you Jared for all the suggestions!

Comment: @shinobi20 Sorry, my comment wasn't clear at all - especially the pronoun. Trying again, without any pronouns this time: If a proposition is false, then a single counterexamples proves that the proposition is false. Producing a single counterexample is a valid way to prove that a proposition is false.

Comment: @JasonZimba With your restated sentence, I understand already what you've said. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for inviting me to clarify, it really was misleading before.

Comment: Indeed, this can hold for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $f$, the characteristic function of the rationals, and $g = -f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the addition can definitely exist, just take the following two step functions:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \geq 0 \\
-1 & x < 0 \end{cases} \\
g(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & x \geq 0 \\
1 & x < 0 \end{cases} \\
f(x) + g(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \geq 0 \\
0 & x < 0 \end{cases} \rightarrow f(x) + g(x) = 0
$$

This is how you need to think.  The same thing can happen when multiplying.  Perhaps the first function is $0$ on the left and the second function is $0$ on the right.  Then at the point of discontinuity they could both multiply (on each side) to give $0$ from both sides.

Note that you don't always have to make the resulting function equal to $0$ (just look at the above step functions, I could just shift both functions up by $1$ and then the addition would be $f(x) +g(x) = 2$ not $0$).

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\dfrac1{x-a}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac1{a-x}$

Answer (score 1):

a) Yes addition can exists if $g = -f$, we have $\lim_ag$ does not exist but $\lim_a f+g=\lim_a0=0$ exists. If $f(x)\not=0$, then $\lim_ag=\lim_a1/f$ does not exists but $\lim_a fg=\lim_a1=1$ exists.

b) If $\lim_a f$ and $\lim_a f+g$ exists then $\lim_ag=\lim_a[(f+g)-f]=\lim_a(f+g)-\lim_af$. Thus must exists.

c) Suppose for sake of contradiction that $\lim_a f+g$ exists.  Then by (b) it follows that $\lim_a g$ must exists. Contradiction.

d) No. If $\lim_af=0$ then we cannot use an argument as (a). For example suppose that $g(x)=-1$ for $x\le a$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x>a$. Then

$$\lim_{\uparrow a}fg=\lim_{\uparrow a}-f=0;\;\;\lim_{\downarrow a}fg=\lim_{\downarrow a}f=0$$

Thus $\lim_a fg=0$. But $\lim_a g$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), let $f =1 + 1_\mathbb{Q}$, $g=-f$. Then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not exist for any $a$ and similarly for $g$.
Note that $f+g = 0$, hence the limit of the sum exists, and note that ${f \over g} = -1$, hence the limit of the quotient exists.

For (b) since $g(x) = (f(x)+g(x)) - f(x)$ and subtraction is continuous, we see that $\lim_x g(x) = \lim_x (f(x)+g(x)) - \lim_x f(x)$.

(c) follows immediately from (b).

For (d), let $f(x) = 0$, and $g$ be the $g$ from Part (a). Then we see that $\lim_x (f) = 0, \lim_x f(x)g(x) = 0$, but clearly $\lim_x g(x) $ still does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

take $f$ be a function limit not existing on $a$

and let $g=-f$

thus when x goes to $a$ limit not exists

but $f+g=f-f=0$

thus limit of $f+g=f-f$ is exists and equal to zero